# Warning: No -m.map found for TS1

Tags: warnings, font-encodings

I'm using the [`cmap` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmap), the [`mmap` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mmap) and the [`textcomp` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) along with them and I'm getting the following error when trying to include the `\copyright` symbol:

```
Package mmap Warning: !!! No -m.cmap file found for TS1 !!!
```

I have a pretty basic understanding of how `cmap` and `mmap` work... can anyone explain this warning to me and tell me how to get rid of it? (I know it's just an innocent warning, but I like to brag about my TeX files compiling with none :P)

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[resetfonts]{cmap}
\RequirePackage[useTeX]{mmap}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}


\begin{document}

  \copyright

\end{document}
```

PS: I read that the `\RequirePackage` method was preferred for `cmap` and `mmap`, can't remember where though... can anyone elaborate on this matter please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from the [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mmap/README) file of the `mmap` package that the TS1 encoding is not (yet) supported :

> TODO:
>    add *.cmap files for other font encodings (contributions are welcome):
>      TS1, OT2, IL2, ...

So the package issues a warning when LaTeX finds a symbol (`\copyright`) that uses TS1 encoding.

Comment: <facepalm> Alright, how does one go about producing one such file? I have no problem in contributing it but I don't know where to start.

Comment: @mpr I don't know but this seems to be a cookbook reference: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5014.CIDFont_Spec.pdf pages 41 and seq.